fsck, mke2fs or e2fsck when fdisk shows but lsblk does not show info for a failing ssd?
Kubuntu 22.04. I started to suspect issues on a SSD when I could not remove files and folders from it any more, sadly badblocks confirmed that there are a lot of bad blocks. The SSD is not used to boot Linux but a separate 2nd SSD for data separate from the Linux system install, there is also no Windows anywhere on this box. To my horror I do not have a backup of the data, this includes family and work data, going forward I know I will have to follow the 3-2-1 backup strategy. Keeping calm, reading manuals, posts, replies and hoping for the best.
In PartedMagic I tried to create an ddrescue image of the SSD with gddrescue.
ddrescue -f -n -v /dev/sdb dev_sdb_image.img dev_sdb_recovery.log

non-trimmed: 13025 KB
bad-sector: 0 B
bad areas: 0 B
read errors: 375

However that failed after 1d 5h 39m at 99.16% as the destination was full. Not sure if I can even use that image. Write error: No space left on device. I am currently waiting for a larger HDD so create a new image.
Since I needed 1 folder from the SSD at work I pugged it in with a UBS/SATA adapter, was able to get the files safely with
rsync --archive --progress --verbose --human-readable /source/ /destination/ --log-file=/restore.log

and safely remove the SSD again. That was yesterday. Today I tried to plug in the SSD through the USB/SATA adapter again to get more folders and files form it but it does not work.
dmesg log
[  861.270830] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  861.271143] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[  861.271677] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  861.271686] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  861.272112] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  861.281356]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2
[  861.281545] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  987.435570] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  987.443424] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 0, async page read
[  987.443467] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 0, async page read
[  987.487303] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  987.487331] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK

lsblk -a
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdb           8:16   0   3.6T  0 disk
├─sdb1        8:17   0   3.4T  0 part
└─sdb2        8:18   0   200G  0 part

sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-28-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB
Serial Number:    
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 f71203d5c
Firmware Version: SVT01B6Q
User Capacity:    4’000’787’030’016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed May  1 11:54:24 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Read SMART Data failed: scsi error aborted command

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error aborted command
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

Read SMART Log Directory failed: scsi error aborted command
Read SMART Error Log failed: scsi error aborted command
Read SMART Self-test Log failed: scsi error aborted command
Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

There are lots of posts and videos about Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB failing from a batch created before 2021/11, if you have one from before that date, do yourself a huge favour and backup your data immediately. This SSD is form 2021/03.
sudo fdisk -l
This took about 10 minutes to complete..
...
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: 2105
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 7394607103 7394605056  3.4T Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb2  7394607104 7814035455  419428352  200G Linux filesystem

sudo fsck /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdb

While this was in progress the name of the /dev/sb1 partition, DATA, shortly became visible in Dolphin and then vanished again. This did happen without me trying to load the mount the SSD, it just happened automatically while the above command was running.
Unsure about how to proceed I tried checking for the filesystem with lsblk -f but that did not show any results, however the above fdisk -l shows that it is a Linux filesystem, I am also fairly sure I formatted it with ext4 in Gparted before using it.
lsblk -f
NAME     FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
...
sdb
├─sdb1
└─sdb2

sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
DATA contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Error reading block 53493762 (Input/output error) while reading directory block.  Ignore error? no

Error reading directory block 53493762 (inode 13372339): Input/output error
Continue? no

e2fsck: aborted

DATA: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

It seems the 2nd partition on the SSD is fine and just /dev/sdb1 is affected.
sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb2
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sdb2: clean, 1120854/13107200 files, 16540762/52428544 blocks

How do I now best proceed please ?
1.
Try and repair the partition /dev/sdb1 with the Input/output error with fsck ?
sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1 ?
2.
Try and repair the magic number in the super-block of the SSD ?
mke2fs -n /dev/sdb
fsck -b $SUPERBLOCK_OUTPUT
3.
Try to run e2fsck ?
e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdb1
e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb1
Very needless to say, learning a lesson the real bad and hard way here, there is 2 kinds of people, those you have backups and those who loose data, yes I know. Thank you for any help.

If the block device is not showing up you wouldn't be able to use any of these tools.  Before doing anything else that attempts to modify the drive (even if it's to repair) I'd be taking an image of the drive, as a file, onto a different device.  Using dd if in a terminal.  If the system is having problems reading the device, then that may fail though.. though in some cases an SSD may fail in a way that read-only access is kinda ok.
If it succeeds, you can then try to run your recovery tools on that image.  Non-destructively if possible
